# Difference between hash["key"] = "value" and hash.store("key","value")

Tags: ruby, hashmap, hash

In Ruby, what's the difference between

```
hash["key"] = "value"
```

and

```
hash.store("key","value")
```

Comment: In the docs they're listed as being the same thing.

Answer (score 5):

In order to understand it we can inspect the ruby source code. The source code for the class `hash` can be found [here](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/9f1c009497431a5fd161eb530f8f1ccfbe0acac3/hash.c).

The method `[]=` is defined at line [4017](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/9f1c009497431a5fd161eb530f8f1ccfbe0acac3/hash.c#L4017) as:

```
rb_define_method(rb_cHash,"[]=", rb_hash_aset, 2);
```

The method `store` is defined at line [4018](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/9f1c009497431a5fd161eb530f8f1ccfbe0acac3/hash.c#L4018) as:

```
rb_define_method(rb_cHash,"store", rb_hash_aset, 2);
```

As you can see they both point to the C function `rb_hash_aset`, this means that the method `store` is simply an alias for the `[]=` method.

Comment: You can compare the methods from within Ruby: `Hash.instance_method(:store) == Hash.instance_method(:[]=)
#=> true`

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between the two.

If you run both in irb (interactive ruby), you'll get the same result.

Say you have a hash named list, with the following key/value pairs:

```
list = { "item" => "Milk", "quantity" => 2 }
```

When you add the key, "price" with the value, 10, using

```
list.store("price", 10)
```

list, will now return,

```
# => {"item"=>"Milk", "quantity"=>2, "price"=>10}
```

Likewise, deleting the key, "price"

```
list.delete("price")
```

and then adding the key again, using

```
list["price"] = 10
```

list, will also return,

```
# => {"item"=>"Milk", "quantity"=>2, "price"=>10}
```

Comment: "They are just two different ways of doing the same thing." – They are more than that: they are *aliases*, IOW, they are not two *different* ways, they are the *same* way, just under a different name.